# NSString replace repeated newlines with single newline

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have an `NSString` which can have multiple \n in between the string. I need to replace the multiple occurrence of \n's with a single \n.

I tried this code:

```
newString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n\n" withString:@"\n"];
```

But this does not give the desired result if a series of "\n\n\n\n\n\n" is encountered in the string. In this case, they will be replaced with "\n\n\n".

What should I do so that all more than one "\n"s be replaced with single "\n"?

Thanks to all!

Update: Adding a screenshot for `UITextView` to which the filtered string is set as text. The new lines seem to be more than one after writing code as suggested by Attila H in answer.
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might use [NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html). This is the most simple and elegant way:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\n+" options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *newString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@"\n"];
```

Comment: Remark: The NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive option is not necessary here.

Comment: Well, indeed. Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help but unfortunately, I can still see new lines being added. I am setting the filtered string to a UITextView. I am sharing a screenshot for the UITextView.

Comment: @AttilaH please see the attached screen shot. Actually the text is in Arabic. Do I need to add something more because the text being in Arabic?

Comment: Are you sure that they are `\n`s? If not, they are not matched by the regex.

Comment: The original string is received from server in JSON, and is in UTF-8 format. Is there any way I can verify it for your question?

Comment: Try this: `NSUInteger count = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];`

Comment: @AttilaH for this particular text being shown in textView, it returned count = 10;

Comment: Hmmm, strange. Try replacing new lines with some placeholder like @"*** Newline ***" instead of @"\n" and let's see if they are really replaced.

Comment: @AttilaH It wasn't working for me because the text had whitespaces after every \n. But your answer was correct and it helped.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for an Updated **Swift 4** Answer:

```
extension String {

   func removeMultipleNewlinesFromMiddle() -> String {
       let returnString = trimmedString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n+", with: "\n", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
       return (returnString)
   }
}
```

**Usage :**

```
let str = "Hello \n\n\nWorld \n\nHow are you\n?"
print (str.removeMultipleNewlinesFromMiddle())
```

**Output :**

Hello

World

How are you

?

Comment: Similar call exists for Swift 3.  options: .regularExpression is fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way

```
NSArray *arrSplit = [s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
                s = [arrSplit componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
```

Hope it may help you..

Comment: @sanijit Did u check this one? if so take this string plz check NSString *string = @"Helloooooooo \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n hiiiiiii this is true \n good work \n\n very nice \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

Comment: @Nag_iphone thanks to let me know it is not working for this case. Then what is the meaning of the newlinecharacter(set)? Do let me know? Prior to your comment I had some wrong concept.