# How should I remove all the empty lines from a string

Tags: ios, string, swift

I get a string value from an api, and there's a lot of useless empty lines:

```
bla bla bla


bla

bla bla bla
```

I want to remove those empty lines to get this result:

```
bla bla bla
bla
bla bla bla
```

How can I proceed ?

Comment: use this [anyString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]]

Comment: Using swift its `anyString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet())`

Comment: @MuhammadRaheelMateen and AtheistP3ace That will remove whitespace from the ends of the String, not the middle of it.

Comment: OP, can you please include the attempts you've already made to solve the problem?

Comment: I think that you actually want to remove duplicate new lines? e.g. `\n\n`?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove all blank lines

Comment: See the Obj-C answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876053/nsstring-replace-repeated-newlines-with-single-newline or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360905/objective-c-replace-newline-sequences-with-one-space

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32691559/remove-empty-lines-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 19, accepted):

edit/update:

**Swift 5.2 or later**

You can use `StringProtocol` split method

```
func split(maxSplits: Int = Int.max, omittingEmptySubsequences: Bool = true, whereSeparator isSeparator: (Character) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Substring]
```

And pass a Character property `isNewline` as KeyPath. Then you just need to use joined(separator: "\n")` to concatenate your string again:

```
let string = "bla bla bla\n\n\nbla\nbla bla bla\n"
let lines = string.split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline)
let result = lines.joined(separator: "\n")

print(result)  // "bla bla bla\nbla\nbla bla bla"
```

Or as an extension of `StringProtocol`:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var lines: [SubSequence] { split(whereSeparator: \.isNewline) }
    var removingAllExtraNewLines: String { lines.joined(separator: "\n") }
}
```

---

```
string.lines  // ["bla bla bla", "bla", "bla bla bla"]
string.removingAllExtraNewLines  // "bla bla bla\nbla\nbla bla bla"
```

Comment: Great extension for String!! extension String {
  func removeMoreThanOneEndOfLines () -> String {
    var linesArray: [String] = []
    self.enumerateLines { line, _ in linesArray.append(line) }
    return linesArray.filter{!$0.isEmpty}.joined(separator: "\n")
  }
}

Comment: @abanet You should extend `StringProtocol` instead of `String` since Swift 4 to support substrings as well

Answer (score 4):

Here's an easy way to do it:

```
import Foundation

let string = "bla bla bla\n\n\nbla\n\nbla bla bla\n"
var filtered = ""
string.enumerateLines({if !$0.line.isEmpty { filtered.appendContentsOf("\($0.line)\n") }})
print(filtered)
// => bla bla bla
// => bla
// => bla bla bla
```

Another way without creating a mutable variable:

```
let newString = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()).filter({!$0.isEmpty}).joinWithSeparator("\n")
```

Comment: Elegant one-line solution

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5.1 one line version**

This removes all extra(at the end of the text) and intermediate spaces.

```
    let extraSpaceRemoveText = text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).components(separatedBy: .newlines).filter{!$0.isEmpty}.joined(separator: "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

MuhammadRaheelMateen's and AtheistP3ace's suggestions are headed in the right direction, but `whitespaceCharacterSet‌` would also remove spaces in between words. You should only remove `newlineCharacterSet`.

But even then, "trimming" would only remove the whitespace at the ends; and as Suthan said, you only want to remove duplicate new lines.

Try separating the string into components separated by newlines, filtering out "", then rejoining with a newline:

```
let string = blaString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet()).filter(){$0 != ""}.joinWithSeparator("\n")
```